# Iterating over object of the class

Tags: java, stack

In the following code, I instantiated an object of the class and wondering whether I am heading in the right direction or not?. Since it's not a collection, is there a way I can iterate through the items I am inserting using stack class object? Or is there something wrong with the solution design part?

```
package stack;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class StackUsingQPartII {


    Queue<Integer> q1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Queue<Integer> q2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public int pop() {
        if (q1.peek() == null) {
            System.out.println("The stack is empty, nothing to return");
            int i = 0;
            return i;
        } else {
            int pop = q1.remove();
            return pop;
        }
    }

    public void push(int data) {

        if (q1.peek() == null) {
            q1.add(data);
        } else {
                for (int i = q1.size(); i > 0; i--) {
                    q2.add(q1.remove());
                }
                q1.add(data);
                for (int j = q2.size(); j > 0; j--) {
                    q1.add(q2.remove());
                }

             }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {


        StackUsingQPartII st = new StackUsingQPartII ();

        st.push(2);



    }

}
```

Comment: do you mean `StackUsingQPartII` class for iterating?

Comment: Yeah basically, I will have to deal with its object to iterate or print if I want to. Say for example I want to display the pushed element `2`, then I am stuck with what I have done over there

Comment: I don't think that is possible. with the current implementation.

Comment: Hmm, What alternative would you suggest then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the class enclosing your stack implementation return an `iterator()` to iterate over the elements in the queue. The iterator() functionality can simply be delegated to the underlying container class holding the stack elements.

```
    public class StackUsingQPartII implements Iterable<Integer>{

        @Override
        public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
            return q1.iterator();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            StackUsingQPartII st = new StackUsingQPartII();
            st.push(2);

            Iterator<Integer> it = st.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Integer i = it.next();
                System.out.println(i);
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: And to concat iterators of both `q1` and `q2` queues Guava's [Iterators.concat](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#concat%28java.util.Iterator,%20java.util.Iterator%29) can be used.

Comment: Awesome. That worked.  @MarcinKról Could you please elaborate why were you recommending me to concat iterators? Is it required somewhere in my code ?

Comment: @Dan You are using 2 queues internally. I thought you might want to iterate through both at once.